# java table CustomTableCellRenderer change row color according to cell content value

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

i am developing java application .i want to show data in a table which has 3 column name course and year .i use tablerenderer according to a tutorial found on internet.this code actually doing is colorize rows with  cyan and gray color according to row number ..but i want to set cyan color to row only if year column (value of year) equals to certain value let's say 3.which mean if 3rd row year column value  equal 5 then 3rd row color should cyan else it should gray. this is my code i found on internet ..so how can i modify it for my goal ??

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;


public class CustomCellRenderer{
  JTable table;
  TableColumn tcol;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new CustomCellRenderer();
  }

  public CustomCellRenderer(){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a Custom Cell Reanderer!");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  String data[][] = {{"Vinod","Computer","3"},
   {"Rahul","History","2"},
   {"Manoj","Biology","5"},
   {"Sanjay","PSD","6"}};
  String col [] = {"Name","Course","Year"};
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);
  table = new JTable(model);
  tcol = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
  tcol.setCellRenderer((TableCellRenderer) new CustomTableCellRenderer());
  tcol = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
  tcol.setCellRenderer((TableCellRenderer) new CustomTableCellRenderer());
  tcol = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
  tcol.setCellRenderer((TableCellRenderer) new CustomTableCellRenderer());
  JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
  header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
  panel.add(pane);
  frame.add(panel);
  frame.setSize(500,150);
  frame.setUndecorated(true);
  frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, 
Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
  Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
   table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

  if (isSelected) {
  cell.setBackground(Color.green);
  } 
  else {
  if (row % 2 == 0 ) {
  cell.setBackground(Color.cyan);
  }
  else {
  cell.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
  }
  }
  return cell;
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are given the row number, all you need to do is read from your model the content in the 'year' column for the given row number.

Comment: This site is not for helping people who don't know how to program to modify code they found on the internet.

Comment: i can modify many codes but only confused with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply as in CustomTableCellRenderer class

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
String colYear = model.getColumnName(2);
int colYearValue = Integer.valueOf((String) model.getValueAt(row, 2));

if (colYearValue == 3) {
    cell.setBackground(Color.cyan);
} else {
    cell.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but i want to set cyan color to row only if year column (value of year) equals to certain value

Don't use individual renderers. Instead you can use the approach found in [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).